# DNS Issue github pages

Tags: html, https, dns, github-pages, insecure-connection

**When i enter the url https://www.troosbouw.com and press enter, browser says connection insecure.**
However when i enter https://troosbouw.com or troosbouw.com and press enter, apparently the connection is considered secure by the browser. I'm using firefox browser.

**I think its an issue with my dns settings** since i am redirecting www but not https://www

*DNS settings (google domains):*
[image]

**Will adding a cname record for https://www which redirects to troosbouw.com (apex domain) fix this issue?**

--
i'm using github pages for my website. I have the setting enforce HTTPS enabled and when im actually on the website my browser says the connection is secure (please see image below). However when i enter the website via a certain url (see below) the browser says the connection isnt secure and doesnt want to open the page. I don't know why.

**Repository:**
[github rep](https://github.com/MaartenDominicus/TroosCom)

How come when i enter the first url the browser doesn't consider the website secure when i do have enforce https enabled in github pages settings?

**Connection security info** image (screenshot taken after entering website via the other two url's which don't give me the connection not secure message):

[image]

**Github pages settings:**
[image]

The same issue is also present for the main domain (when user enters url https://www.troosbouw.com the browser says connection insecure but with https://troosbouw.com and [www.troosbouw.com](http://www.troosbouw.com) and troosbouw.com it works fine)

What am i doing wrong? Is there a way to make it work with https://www.troosbouw.com?